# Best way to analyse change in amplitude of cyclic data?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have some cyclic data that I'm trying to analyse which I've posted below:
[image]

I would like to analyse some overall trends of the data. The peak-to-peak amplitude appears to be decreasing, however, I'm not entirely sure how to quantify this. Also, there is clearly an overall downwards trend. I can obviously just fit a line of best fit to determine the rate of change, but are there any alternative ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> a line of best fit

You propose feeding *all* the observed points to
[OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).
There are alternatives using fewer points.

Compute local maxima (where slope goes from positive to negative),
and run OLS just on those.
Repeat with the set of local minima.

Now you have an opportunity to do a sanity check,
verifying the two lines are of similar slope.